# How to include image file in Webpack 5 without url-loader

Tags: file, webpack, webpack-5

I have an application with this structure:

```
/
/src/index.js
/src/styles/index.css
/static/background.png
```

The stylesheet is trying to use the PNG file like this:

```css
// index.css
.page {
  background-image: url("../../../static/background.png");
}
```

Now I would like to avoid using `url-loader` if possible and just copy the PNG file to `dist` folder for production but also have it work with dev server.

I have tried using this rule:

```js
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'asset/resource',
          options: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
          },
        },
      },
```

I read about built-in loader such as `asset/resource` however I fail to understand how to set it to read the PNG file from `static` folder.

I'm getting error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/index.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Error: Can't resolve './background.png' in '/Users/user/app/src/styles'
```

I use these rules to process CSS:

```js
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ],
      },
```